# Use metadata.annotations in CSI Kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have my custom CSI driver. I want to add a customized annotation in my volume attachment manifest file which I want my CSI driver to parse and process it accordingly.

How can I pass my annotation to CSI driver and process it in golang code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `CustomResourceDefinion Controller` and process annotation then pass it to your app. You can also use `MutatingAdmissionWebHook` to process annotations to your driver without `CRDs` but if you implement `CRDs` then you will have more features going on to dynamically watch state of apps/cluster and repair/update/delete without user intervention.

Comment: Hi Akın Özer, Thanks for your response. Could you please share some related doc or example that would be of great help to me, I am currently following example on this link https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller.git to create sample CRD controller.

Comment: This guide is great for golang, annotations are just fields like labels so you can expect them in your controller and process interior values: https://www.martin-helmich.de/en/blog/kubernetes-crd-client.html